# Simple but so far unsolveable: Why doesn't my click function work? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enterbutton").click(function(){$("#curtain").fadeOut(1000);});
    }
</script>
```

When I run my page in any browser, the click function doesn't work. I can click all over and around the  element, but nothing happens.

I have already tried putting the code in the jquery file instead, and I have tried using the .on('click', method instead of .click.

Comment: The script last line should close the `ready`  call  like `});`

Comment: Please use tools like [Chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to [learn to debug](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) your code. It'll help you in solving most of your issues, including this one.

Comment: A `<script>` element can either contain code *or* reference an external file via the `src` attribute, but not both.

Comment: If you right button click on Chrome and click in Inspect, then console, errors like these can be readily solved.  You are missing a closing bracket and Chrome console will tell you this right away.

Comment: Ah, such a silly mistake. Thanks for the tip, I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 3):

close script

```
<script src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#enterbutton").click(function(){
        $("#curtain").fadeOut(1000);
     });
   });
</script>
```

if you already have `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` file the above code should work good but if you don't have the source file of jquery you can use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#enterbutton").click(function(){
          $("#curtain").fadeOut(1000);
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Forgot a `});` at the very end.

Comment: So I've updated the code to exactly that, but still, nothing happens no matter what browser I run in. Is there anything else wrong with the code? All the html tags are fine, no errors in spelling or punctuation.

Comment: Nevermind, finally got it. Left some debris in the jquery file while experimenting with adding it to that. Thanks for the help everyone